# (matpolotlib) ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, unix, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am getting the following error when trying to display data values instead of markers:

**Complete Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "plotpoints.py", line 45, in <module>
plt.annotate(grid_x,grid_y)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3405, in annotate
ret = gca().annotate(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 3404, in annotate
a = mtext.Annotation(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/text.py", line 1813, in __init__
annotation_clip=annotation_clip)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/text.py", line 1442, in __init__
x, y = self.xytext = xytext
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

**Code:**

```
m = mapformat()

dx = 0.25

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[-85:64:dx, 34:49:dx]

grid_z = griddata((data[:,1],data[:,0]), data[:,2], (grid_x,grid_y), method='linear')

x,y = m(data[:,1], data[:,0]) # flip lat/lon

grid_x,grid_y = m(grid_x,grid_y)

plt.annotate(grid_x,grid_y)

#m.plot(grid_x,grid_y, 'ko', markersize=2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Atleast put the complete traceback.

Comment: Edited the original post to reflect this..

Comment: What do you want to do with - `plt.annotate(grid_x,grid_y)` ?

Comment: Instead of plotting markers of a lat/lon point (from data[:,0] & data[:,1]), I want to display the data value (from data[,:,2]) that's associated with the lat/lon points.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are calling `annotate` correctly

```
plt.annotate(grid_x,grid_y)
```

That looks like 2 arrays or lists of points (I haven't fully deduced how you define those 2 variables).

But the documentation is:

```
ax.annotate('local max', xy=(3, 1),  ...)
```

The 1st argument is the text and the second a tuple with the coordinates.

I'm guessing that the calling sequence converts your `xgrid` argument to `mtext`, and `ygrid` to its `xytext`

```
x, y = self.xytext = xytext
```

If there are more than 2 values in `ygrid`, this unpacking will produce your error.

`annotate` adds text at a specific point on the plot; it can't be used to label the coordinates of a bunch of data points (at least not in one call).

Answer (score 0):

One of the functions that you're calling on the right is returning more values than there are variables to assign to on the left.

For example, if you do the following in a REPL:

```
a,b = [1,2,3]
```

You'll get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

It'll help to see which line the code is failing at - this way, you'll know which function is returning too many variables.